# How to precompile a pdf asset in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

In Rails 3.2.11 app I'm trying to publish my app to Heroku.

In the assets folder I have a pdf subfolder with some pdf files inside.

In my production.rb file I have added the following:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w[*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif *.pdf]
config.assets.precompile += ["*.js"]
config.assets.precompile += ["*.css"]
config.assets.precompile += ['pdf/*']
config.assets.precompile += %w( ricerca_wg.pdf  )
```

If I check the pdf assets paths on my console I get:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths
# [
#   "/Users/Augusto/Sites/wisegrowth/app/assets/images",
#   "/Users/Augusto/Sites/wisegrowth/app/assets/javascripts",
#   "/Users/Augusto/Sites/wisegrowth/app/assets/pdf",
#   "/Users/Augusto/Sites/wisegrowth/app/assets/stylesheets",
#   "/Users/Augusto/Sites/wisegrowth/vendor/assets/javascripts",
#   "/Users/Augusto/Sites/wisegrowth/vendor/assets/stylesheets",
#   "/Users/Augusto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/jquery-rails-2.3.0/vendor/assets/javascripts",
#   "/Users/Augusto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/assets/javascripts",
#   "/Users/Augusto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/formtastic-2.1.1/app/assets/stylesheets"
# ]
```

But when I run

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

everything is precompiled BUT the pdf files and in my production app on Heroku I get the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (ricerca_wg.pdf isn't precompiled):
```

Comment: I don't think PDF files need to be compiled, is it generated by the app using wickedhtmlpdf or some tool like that? If it is, you don't need to compile the PDF files but the css files for that PDF layout (if it's a different layout than the one for the application). 
If it's not generated and it's just a static PDF I'd rather store it in an amazon s3 bucket or some other cloud storage and just retrieve the URL when necessary.

Comment: Thanks Juan, the pdf file is static, so I could store it on S3.  Anyway I would like to know how to host it oh Heroku like I previously did.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think a pdf must be "precompiled".

if you just want to access the pdf from your app without using another service like S3, you can just put that pdf folder on your public folder of the rails app, and they will be available on the app as an static file.

```
www.domain.com/pdf/ricerca_wg.pdf
```

just be sure that the public/pdf folder isn't in the `gitignore` and it must work.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the `ricerca_wg.pdf` is under `/Users/Augusto/Sites/wisegrowth/app/assets/pdf/`? If not, simply

- remove `config.assets.precompile += %w( ricerca_wg.pdf  )`
- move `ricerca_wg.pdf` under `/Users/Augusto/Sites/wisegrowth/app/assets/pdf/` - it should be precompiled along with other pdf files from this directory

Comment: Hi Andrey, yes ricerca_wg.pdf is already in /Users/Augusto/Sites/wisegrowth/app/assets/pdf/ but pdfs in that directory are not precompiled at the moment

Comment: @Augusto did you set `config.serve_static_assets` to `true`?

Comment: Yes, in production.rb